# extending jquery-ui menu widget fails, but it shouldnt

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, extending, jquery-widgets

This is just a quick question since I cant figure out what's the actual problem here, maybe someone has more experience in extending a jquery-ui widget.

I'm trying to change some behaviour in the `menu._close` method, extending the widget like this:

```
( function($, undefined ) {
    $.widget('ui.menu', $.ui.menu, {
        _close: function(startMenu) {
            this._super('_close', startMenu)
                    console.log('extension works!')
        } 
    } )
} (jQuery) );
```

As far as I can tell from the sources I found, this is the correct way. But now, the problem is the `_super` method. It should call the original `menu._close` method, and it does - delivering the only parameter `startMenu` to it. But the parent method fails.

Here is the source of the original jquery-ui `menu._close` method:

```
_close: function( startMenu ) {
    if ( !startMenu ) {
        startMenu = this.active ? this.active.parent() : this.element;
    }

    startMenu
        .find( ".ui-menu" )
        .hide()
        .attr( "aria-hidden", "true" )
        .attr( "aria-expanded", "false" )
        .end()
        .find( "a.ui-state-active" )
        .removeClass( "ui-state-active" );
}
```

Now, it tells me `TypeError: startMenu.find is not a function`, and yes, it's not because `this.element` is not an actual jQuery object. But my question is, why?

I only extended the method, whitout changing any functionality, only adding a debug mesasge **after** the original method was called, delivering the only parameter to it. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance, have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[_super()](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_super) already knows which base method it should call, so passing its name is redundant.

You only have to write:

```
_close: function(startMenu) {
    this._super(startMenu);
    console.log("extension works!");
}
```

In your current code, the first argument passed to the base method will be the method name instead of `startMenu`, which will indeed result in the base method failing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well, then I did get something wrong on this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/scottgonzalez/962848 here the _super() method uses '_create' as parameter, so I figured it was needed. (I looked up the `_super` method somewhere else too, and there it was documented that way too) maybe I've read outdated informations then.

Comment: @Katai, that tutorial may refer to a previous release of jQuery UI (the widget factory was revamped since then). That said, even the official documentation is weird (for instance, saying `_super()` does not accept arguments). I double-checked in the current source code, and the pattern definitely is "do not pass the method name, do pass any other argument".